# Power-Cut beeping

Tags: power-supply, sound

I have a device that should stay connected to power at all times.
Now when someone unplugs the device from the power there should beeper that goes off for one or two seconds, alerting or reminding the person to plug it in again.

I would like to use a standard 5V beeper but I'm not sure how to design this. I would assume that a capacitor is being charged while on the power and that the power cut would use that power to power the beeper.

Comment: what is your specific question?

Answer (score 1):

It should be a piezo self-oscillating buzzer that might draw only 10 mA but only works down to 3V ? Check?

- then you can design the holdup C value.

But it may not last a few seconds unless C is big enough and you pulse the buzzer with a slow clock to control the discharge charge duration.

eg.

C=Ic dt/dV ~ 10mA *2s/2V= 10mF